# Problem in using CCCamera

Tags: iphone, camera, cocos2d-iphone

I am going to work on a game project. I am using cocos2d. I want to use cccamera class of cocos2d. Please tell me about any tutorial on cccamera. I want to implement more or less like angry birds, throwing the ball that reaches its destination facing the obstacles in the way.
So when the ball moves ahead the scene accordingly moves back depending on speed of the ball.
How to manage all that. I think i should use cccamera.

Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

CCCamera, per the documentation is used for 3D effects (http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/latest-stable/interface_c_c_camera.html) and recommends the use of CCFollow (http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/latest-stable/interface_c_c_follow.html) for 2D related effects (such as following the birds forward, etc).